# How to access each numerical element in cv::Point_<int> type?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, point

I have a cv::Rect object. From it, I am getting the bottom right point of the rectangle. I want to separate the point object into two separate `int` variables. How do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
cv::Rect rectangle;
bottomRight = rectangle.br() // this gives me a Point <int>, such as [545, 364]
```

I want to separate `bottomRight` into its two coordinate points as different int variables, such as:

```
// bottomRight is [545, 364]
bottomRight_x = bottomRight[0] // should be 545
bottomRight_y = bottomRight[1] // should be 364
```

When I try to subscript, I get this error:

> type 'Point_' does not provide a subscript operator

In Python, I would just subscript as above. How do I do this in C++?

Comment: Too lazy to open Visual Studio right now... Isn't there `bottomRight.x` and `bottomRight.y`?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d4e/classcv_1_1Point__.html Looks like `x` and `y` are public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *x* and *y* ordinates of the `cv::Point_<T>` structure are stored as `public` member variables (of type `T`) called `x` and `y` (rather than as a 2-element array).

So, your code should be:

```cpp
// bottomRight is [545, 364]
bottomRight_x = bottomRight.x;
bottomRight_y = bottomRight.y;
```

(That is, if you *really* need to isolate them from the structure itself.)